# How to Code this SSL Certificate Dialog, with Selenium IEdriver "request for permission to use a key" IE 8 9 11

Tags: selenium, java

Can anyone help me with sample code please. 
I have to login with SSL client certificate to authenticate in IE, this UI only works in IE. 
I have this Autoit Script but the popup is not being read by Autoit.

```
WinWaitActivate (“Request For Permission to Use a Key”)
Send(“{SHIFTUP}{SHIFTUP}{TAB}”)
Send(“password”)
Send(“{ENTER}”)
```

[image]

I have also tried with Java Robot and:

```
driver.switchTo().window("Request For Permission to Use a Key");
```

Comment: Is this a modal window?

Comment: yes it is. i do see this error

Answer (score 1):

Use you browser window name to find the window. Then perform the certificate accept sequence. That should solve your problem.

https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions.htm

```
SeleniumTest.java

package tests;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Handling_Windows_Based_Prompt {

      public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
      WebDriver c1 = new FirefoxDriver();
      c1.get(“http://my.test..in”);
      Runtime.getRuntime().exec(“E:\\authenticationFF.exe”);

     }

 }

    authenticationFF.au3

    WinWaitActive(“Authentication Required”,””,”10″)
    If WinExists(“Authentication Required”) Then
       Send(“CHENNAI/sumand{TAB}”)
       Send(“smartek@1212{ENTER}”)
    EndIf
```

Comment: Thanks. I believe this popup is not coming from IE.
WinWaitActive(“Request For Permission to Use a Key”,””,”10″) If WinExists(“Request For Permission to Use a Key”) Then Send("{SHIFTUP}{SHIFTUP}{TAB}") Send("password") Send("{ENTER}")

EndIf